# form_for not using custom getter when loading attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My model `Expense` has modified getter and setter for the `quantity` attribute in order to apply the currency being used:

Here's the getter:

```
def quantity
    update_rates
    c = read_attribute(:quantity)
    if @@current_currency != "EUR"
        @@eu_bank.exchange(c*100, "EUR", @@current_currency).cents/100.0
    else
        c
    end
end
```

This is being used in cases when `@expense.quantity` is called, like in the index or show view. However, when the `form_for(@expense)` tag is used for editing an expense, the value of the quantity loaded isn't what it should be. It is displayed as extracted directly from the database (I guess) and the getter I defined is not being used:

```
<%= form_for(@expense) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :quantity %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
<% end %>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is to force the value of the `text_field`, like:

```
<%= f.text_field :quantity, value: @expense.quantity %>
```

But I think this can be solved in a better way.

- How is the `quantity` stored relative to the currency and stuff?
- How does the setter look?

Comment: the quantity is stored in the database as euros, and the conversion is made based on the exchange between euros and the current currency

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation is trying to handle 3 things:

- attribute getting
- currency conversion
- view formatting

Would suggest that you delegate the extra responsibility to a different class and keep that method limited to attribute getting.

View related model logic can go into a presenter. You can keep the conversion logic in the presenter or create a separate module/class for it depending on how complex it is.

http://robertomurray.co.uk/blog/2014/decorators-presenters-delegators-rails/